# Saving Timestamp data but only with date in Java

Tags: java, jdbc

One of my database column is of type Timestamp format (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss) but the data saved in it is 2014-06-13 00:00:00. So the time component is not saved to the database table.

I am trying to INSERT data to that table but unable to remove the time component from my data.

Here is what I am doing:

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
java.sql.Timestamp timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(time);
```

So the time (long) = 1402710418003 and timestamp=2014-06-13 21:46:58.003

Is there a way I can remove the time part from timestamp? 
Ex: 2014-06-13
OR
Ex: 2014-06-13 00:00:00

This is my prepared statement:

```
java.util.Date currentDate= new java.util.Date();
sql_statement4.setTimestamp(6,new Timestamp(currentDate.getTime()));
```

sql_statement4 is a PreparedStatement object.

I want the value to be in Timestamp format.

How do I do this?

Comment: Won't it be removed by the db call anyway?

Comment: Use PreparedStatement.setDate instead of setTimestamp

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis What do you mean DB call? I am INSERTing the data. No the time component is also getting inserted.

Comment: @BrettOkken Currently this is what I do.  sql_statement4.setTimestamp(6,new Timestamp(currentDate.getTime()));

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the call (from your comment),

```
sql_statement4.setTimestamp(6,new Timestamp(currentDate.getTime()));
```

to

```
sql_statement4.setDate(6,new java.sql.Date(currentDate.getTime()));
```